# Is it possible for me to exchange information with Twilio APIs?

Tags: php, xml, twilio

I'm trying to identify the user who is making Twilio requests from my system. Is there a way I can encrypt the information of this user, send it to Twilio along with the allowed parameters & receive the same along with Twilio's response?

EDIT: I may not have been very clear. I'm trying to make calls using Twilio's API from a web-app (PHP). I need to send the user (who is trying to establish the call)'s details & our API key to Twilio so that I can identify the user when I receive the response from Twilio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include custom URL parameters in Twilio's webhook callback URL.  Although the Twilio system itself will not make use of this information, it will be passed back to your php application when the call is answered.  You can use this information to correlate the call to a user or other application specific concept.  Here's an example:

```
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
  '9991231234', // From a valid Twilio number
  '8881231234', // Call this number
  // Call this URL when a call connects and include the custom user_id parameter
  'http://www.yoursite.com/handle_call.php?user_id=41423’
);
```

You can find more information about how the [Twilio REST API and webhooks work together](https://twilio.radicalskills.com/projects/getting-started-with-twilio/2.html#rest-vs-twiml) in the Twilio Skills training.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if it is twilio's responsibility to store additional information that you need to be otherwise handling yourself on your system. Why would twilio take operational overload from your end? Twilio probably has a confirmation token or request id for the twilio request that your system makes (returned via XML/ Json by its API server). You can take that ID and store it against the user_id inside your database (SQL / Mongo / Redis). Use that table to extrapolate information you need such as.

- The number of requests each user made initiated.
- The kind of requests made.
- What time each request went out.
- Result / Response from each request.

Hope this helps.